# how to set conditional reference to range on Python 3, and xrange on Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python-3 code that I would like to be compatible for both python-2 and python-3 keeping the code as is as much as possible.
I would like to use the iteration behavior of range (to iterate over many items).

In order to get an *iterator*:

- python-2 uses **xrange**(N)
- python-3 uses **range**(N)

what is the best way to make it an iterator for python2 with minimal changes as possible?

looking at [this link](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html), it suggests a few ways for range and xrange but couldn't make it work

Comment: Detect the python version and use `range = xrange` if you find the user running python 2. Basically, deliberately redefine `range`

Comment: How large do you expect N to be?

Comment: This might be semantics, but neither `xrange` in python 2 nor `range` in python 3 return iterators, they return an `xrange` or `range` object and you can't use them with `next()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this near the start of the program.

```
import sys
import builtins

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    range = xrange

a = range(100)  # Keep your Python 3 code unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    n_range = xrange
except NameError:
    n_range = range
```

We can set `n_range` as xrange and if it fails, set it as range.

Comment: I think it's much less efficient to catch exception rather than simple `if`

Answer (score 0):

you can detect the version of python at runtime:

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info[0] < 3:
    range = xrange
```

this overrides the regular range behavior in python 2 so make sure your code doesn't use the python 2 range